# Flutter Hive Database Error: Out of Memory Exception

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, out-of-memory, flutter-hive

I'm encountering an "Out of Memory" exception in my Flutter app while using the Hive database package, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it.

```
E/flutter (25087): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Out of Memory
E/flutter (25087): #0 new Uint8List (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:2237:3)
E/flutter (25087): #1 BufferedFileReader.loadBytes (package:hive/src/io/buffered_file_reader.dart:73:18)
E/flutter (25087): #2 _KeyReader._load (package:hive/src/io/frame_io_helper.dart:89:40)
E/flutter (25087): #3 _KeyReader.readKeys (package:hive/src/io/frame_io_helper.dart:69:31)
E/flutter (25087): #4 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:47)
E/flutter (25087): #5 _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
E/flutter (25087): #6 _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:18)
E/flutter (25087): #7 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:846:45)
E/flutter (25087): #8 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:875:13)
E/flutter (25087): #9 Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:647:5)
E/flutter (25087): #10 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:47)
E/flutter (25087): #11 _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
E/flutter (25087): #12 _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:18)
E/flutter (25087): #13 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:846:45)
E/flutter (25087): #14 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:875:13)
E/flutter (25087): #15 Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:647:5)
E/flutter (25087): #16 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:47)
E/flutter (25087): #17 _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
E/flutter (25087): #18 _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:18)
E/flutter (25087): #19 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:846:45)
E/flutter (25087): #20 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:875:13)
E/flutter (25087): #21 Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:647:5)
E/flutter (25087): #22 Future._asyncCompleteWithValue. (dart:async/future_impl.dart:721:7)
E/flutter (25087): #23 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:13)
E/flutter (25087): #24 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1301:19)
E/flutter (25087): #25 _CustomZone.bindCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:1233:23)
E/flutter (25087): #26 _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (25087): #27 _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to help me resolve this "Out of Memory" exception while using the Hive database package in my Flutter app. If you've encountered a similar issue before or have any tips for troubleshooting memory-related errors with Hive, please share them.